# Execute User Event from external url suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a question and I would like to someone help me about it.
I'm triying to set field value to custom record at before submit in context create with user event, it works in user interface, but I need to work it since another script, that script is a suitelet who creates this custom record, but I want to call it from external url.
If i call it from internal url, user event script works, but since external url it does not works.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting a security feature. Maybe try setting the field on the custom record from the Suitelet?

Answer (score 0):

Make the user event script file as Available without login in file cabinet, it could be works..